# Why No Body Talk About Checkout Customization Of Magento 2? My Last Post On This Platform

Tags: discussion, magento2

Why No Body Talk About Checkout Customization Of Magento 2? I Do So Much Search On Internet But I Can't Find Any Proper Solution For Customize Checkout Fieds. So I Decide I Ask Question On This Platform. I Post So many Question Of checkout Customization Here But No Body Have Guts For Answers My Questions.

This Is My Last Post This Platform If No Body Help Me.

Answer (score 16):

Let's take your questions one by one:

- [How To Customize Checkout Page Using One Page Checkout extension Call IWD Agency Magento 2.2.6](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/257719/146) Maybe you don't get an answer to this one because it's not a core related question and not a lot of people used the extension you are using.
- [Geting Error In Checkout Page Magento 2.2.6](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/257640/146) This is the same question as the next one. Please stop asking the same question twice
- [Geting Error In Checkout Page Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/256197/146) This one has an answer, and it looks like a valid one to me. But without your code we cannot guess where exactly is the problem. You need to put in some effort also.
- [How to Customize Checkout Page In Magento 2.2.6 Using checkout_index_index.xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/256181/146) This one is pretty vague. You are asking "How can I do this using that?". Maybe "using that" is not really the way to go. You should re-word the question and explain the desired result, what have you tried, and what problems you got. Dumping a file and a screenshot and expecting a fully working solution it's just lazy.
- [Customize Checkout Page And Remove Postal Code And Extra Fields](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/255725/146) this one has an answer and again, at a first glance, it looks valid. Or at least a nudge in the right direction. Just stating that it doesn't work for you shows laziness again. What does not work for you? what happens when you use that code? Where did you add that code? does it work in the luma theme? maybe there is something wrong with your theme.

And as a personal response (I'm not speaking for everyone else here), I'm usually avoiding bad formatted questions that might spawn 12 other followup questions because I don't have the time to do support. I try to answer straight to the point questions with clearly explained problems, or with problems that I've encountered myself.

Comment: Good shot Maruis :)